# AC blower after changing capacitor

Tags: blower, air, capacitor

My ac blower was not turning on last night.  I changed the capacitor and the blower turned on.  The ac ran fine for maybe a couple hours and the blower is not running again.

Comment: You either have two capacitors or one with 4 wires. The start and the run function

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] and note that this is a Q&A board and that you haven't asked a question - you could spend the extra moments to at least type out "How do I fix it?"... Additionally, at a minimum, we'll need the brand/model if you'd like specific help rather than generalized guesses.